# PHP how to put BLOB data into an array

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am developing a php script, that reads data from a MYSQL database. Using phpmyadmin i can see that all data is in database and in proper format.

The database consists of text columns and a blob column.

I have now come to read back this data. I have used the following code.

```
$query = @"SELECT TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3, IMAGE FROM EXAMPLETABLE";
```

*Do all the sql calls*

Now if i do the following command then it fills the array with the text but null in the image/blob bit

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $posts[] = array($row['TEXT1'], $row['TEXT2'], $row['TEXT3'], $row['IMAGE']);
}
```

Result via Safari

```
[["Gbv","TR","FG",null]]
```

if i do the following i get the image data.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    ECHO $row['IMAGE'];
}
```

**Edit**
So after another look at code (been working far far to hard today) i noticed that i send the array by 
   echo json_encode($posts);

the json_encode is messing up the blob data.

Thanks

Comment: Every single code example, in your question, has an error in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an image from the blob, capture output buffering contents, convert to a jpeg, grab the contents from the buffer, end the output buffering, push the image into the array.

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($row['IMAGE']); 
ob_start(); //start capture of the output buffer
imagejpeg($image, null, 80);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$posts[] = array('text'1 => $row['TEXT1'], 'text2' => $row['TEXT2'], 'text3' => $row['TEXT3'], 'image' => $data);
```

Then do something like:

```
foreach($posts as $post):
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' .  base64_encode($post['image'])  . '" />';
endforeach;
```

That should work for you.